# RStudio Viewer can't visualize plotly map

Tags: r, rstudio, r-plotly

I am very new to ploty package and I am learning to make some interective maps.
I found the code below on https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/#new-to-plotly
and I would like to reproduce it, but the R Viewer window doesn't show the map, only the scale bar.

I have already updated my RStudio version with 3.6.1
I tried to update my release version of RStudio, but apparently I can't. 
I have download it from https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/ and installed it, but when I run

```
rstudioapi::versionInfo()
```

the version shown is still 
$version
[1] ‘1.0.44’

I found those tips on 
https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotly-map-does-not-display-in-viewer-pane/11655/7

Thanks in advance!

Solved, just needed to uninstall and reinstall R and RStudio from scratch.

Comment: in order to check the R version you can type *version* in the console and see the version your currently using; what you found is the version of RStudio

Comment: With RStudio 1.2.1335 and R version 3.6.0 the linked plotly example is working for me.  Perhaps try upgrading your RStudio version (also discussed in the RStudio link you provided.

Comment: Looks like we should close as "not reproducible" on current versions. If the problem is difficulty with updating then perhaps Sonia should got to the Rstudio forums. She will undoubtedly be asked for more information about her OS and what difficulties she is having with the OS-specific instructions.

Comment: @42-, I think you are right! Thanks!